# How to add bitcoins in my wallet?

Tags: wallet

I'm new to this BTC world, one day someone offered me to pay using BTC and made me create a wallet on https://multibit.org

I recently used it to pay for something online, and another transaction and another one ...

Now, my wallet is almost empty and I need more BTC to make more purchase so the question is : How to add bitcoins in my wallet ? *would like to use my credit card

There's only send/receive options in there :)

Thanks for showing me the way

Comment: You can do it with Circle: https://www.circle.com/en

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what country you are in it's hard to answer fully.

But, as Nick said, you can use [Circle](https://www.circle.com/en) to purchase Bitcoins for USD using a credit card.

To further elaborate, Bitcoins are a currency, so the only real way to get them is either [Mining](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining), [Faucets](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_faucet), or by converting your government currency into Bitcoin using an [Exchange](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Exchanges).